# HP Thin Client T410 Network Issues

Tags: networking, voip, thin-client

This may be a pretty ambiguous problem but I'm going to try asking anyway; I'm at a loss for what to do.

I work for a company that runs a mix of Windows desktops/laptops and Windows virtual machines. These virtual machines run through HP Thin Client Smart Zero models, the t410, and t510, and connect using Citrix software.

We just recently completed a phone upgrade, in which we switched from an analog system with Lucent phones, to a Cisco VOIP system. These phones plug from a wall port into the phone, and then from the phone into the computer. The desktops and laptops connect with no issues, as do the t510s. The t410s, however, have some issues.

The network will drop every 2-5 minutes on default connection settings. The phones are set to Auto-negotiate their speed on both the Switch Port and the PC. The t410 is also set to auto-negotiate it's Ethernet speed.

When changing the phone settings to 1000/Full on both the SW and PC, the t410 will randomly not detect the network; it works for some, and not for others.

If the t410 is set to 100/Full, the speed is abysmal; trying to run a desktop is insane, and to even disconnect the desktop in order to change the setting took nearly 10 minutes.

When setting the t410's Ethernet settings, something else odd shows up; there is only Auto, 10 Half/Full, and 100 Half/Full. Any spec sheet online for the t410 says it can handle 10/100/1000, but there are no options to set 1000.

We have yet to find a solution that is not throwing the t410's into a ditch, and my boss wants me and my coworkers to find a solution that isn't buying more t510s. I understand this information may be patchwork and confusing, but I can try to provide any additional information that anyone asks for.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Sorry @DavidPostill, I'm part of this company's IT department as an intern. We're pretty much out of options to try, so I figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with nearly 150 T510's and ultimately HP sent a technician on-site to replace the NIC in every one of them under warranty.  No issues since then.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure theirs are still under warranty. My internship with them is over, but I know they have a contractor coming to look at their VDI solution. Most likely they're all get replaced with Dell's WYSE models, since the HPs have been nothing but trouble for them. Thank you though, I will pass this on!